# How to add the flashlight toggle in the notification panel on my non-rooted SM-N900A

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm trying to add the flashlight toggle in the notification panel on my SM-N900A (Android 5.0).

And so far, I've found the [Notification Toggle app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle)
 that adds toggles to the notification bar.

But I want to add the flashlight to the notification panel.

How can I do that on my non-rooted SM-N900A ?

Comment: That feature you are looking for was introduced  in Android Nougat. Your only option seems to be to root the device and find an Xposed module to add that feature.

Comment: @Firelord It has Android 5.0, btw. Does it change anything to your conclusion ?

Comment: No, it does not.